# How to include a foreign key to unmapped table?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

- I have a legacy database with lots of tables and I don't want to deal with.
- I'm using Code First.
- I enabled Code First migrations.
- I'm using EF Core 3.1

I created a small `DbContext` with a single entity `MyEntity`. This entity **is new and doesn't exist in the database** yet.

The problem is that I want to include a foreign key to a "legacy" table in this new model.

```
public class MyEntity 
{
    [Key] 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LegacyEntityId { get; set; }
}
```

I would like Entity Framework to care only about `MyEntity`, and that it knows that there is a reference to another pre-existent table via `LegacyEntityId`, a table (called "LegacyEntity" DB) that isn't part of the DbContext.

Is is possible to configure Entity Framework to handle this scenario?
I mean, I have a foreign key to an unmapped entity (tables) that isn't modeled in the context.

Comment: So you want the Id but no relation in code? as in legacyEntity won't be represented in code. Then why would you need a FK? You could just use an ID there without any relational properties. Also i gues you could alter your migrations file to insert an FK constraint if you want (there's also a way to do that with dbmodeler i believe)

Comment: Yes, I don't want to have to model the legacy table in the DbContext, but I want the FK to be there to maintain the referential integrity.

Comment: I want it to be a FK, not a regular property, because I will allow the user to specify the `LegacyEntityId` by hand and I would like those ids to be valid (to existing legacy entities)

Answer (score 1):

Going of the comments,

I don't think there's a way to add an FK constraint like you mentioned. If you check the docs, you can only add an FK to another code-first entity;

```cs
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Blog)
            .WithMany(b => b.Posts)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.BlogForeignKey);
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#foreign-key

I worked with EF6 for some time and i don't think such functionality is there.

The only thing i can think of, is to manually execute SQL which adds the FK constraint;

Some migration file:

```cs
migrationBuilder.Sql(
@"
  ALTER TABLE Orders
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID);
");
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#customize-migration-code

In this way, sql will enforce the constraint but your DbContext won't know this. I.e. queries could be denied because of the constraint.